# Habilitar un boton deshabilitar el resto

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen dia, me gustaria saber si alguno saber si alguno podria ayudarme con una duda que tengo, lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo una pagina y cuenta con 3 botones, quiero que al presionar sobre cualquiera de ellos se deshabiliten los otros 2 que queden
Tratando de explicar un poco mejor, al dar click sobre cualquiera de los 3 botones, se desactivan los otros 2

este es el codigo de la funcion, el estilo y mis botones (solo pondre el estilo porque no se si tenga algo que ver con que no funcione)

```js
function active(id) {
          document.getElementById('boton1').disabled=false;
          document.getElementById('boton2').disabled=false;
          document.getElementById('boton3').disabled=false;
          document.getElementById(id).disabled=true;
    }
```

```css
 .boton {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 95px;
        height: 70px;
        background: #51be44;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 300;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: .3s ease all;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    
     }

 {

 }
 .boton::after{
     content:"";
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     background:#08700d;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:1;
     top:-90px;
     left: 0;
     transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
 }
 .boton:hover::after{
     top:0;
 }

 .boton span{
     position:relative;
     z-index:2;
     transition: .3s ease all;
 }
```

```html
<button class="boton1" id="boton1" onclick=" active(id)" value="0"><span class="text-white font-italic"> En carga </span>  <span class="text-white font-italic display-3">
            <asp:Label ID="lblencarga" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></button>
<button class="boton2" id="boton2" onclick=" active(id)" value="0"><span class="text-white font-italic"> En uso </span>  <span class="text-white font-italic display-3">
            <asp:Label ID="Labelenuso" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></button>
<button class="boton3" id="boton3" onclick=" active(id)" value="0"><span class="text-white font-italic"> Extraviado </span>  <span class="text-white font-italic display-3">
            <asp:Label ID="Labelperdido" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></button>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias, buen dia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bien, permíteme proponerte esta posible solución:

Asignas la misma clase a todos los botones.

```
<button class="boton">Boton 1</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 2</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 3</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 4</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 5</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 6</button>
```

Y entonces, con JavaScript, realizas los siguientes pasos:

Primero, obtienes una lista de los botones con tu clase `.boton` con el método [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
  var botones = document.querySelectorAll('.boton');
```

Acto seguido, iteras sobre esta lista para adjuntar un evento de `click` a cada botón. Esto con [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) y [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
botones.forEach(boton =>
{
   boton.addEventListener('click', (e) =>
   {
       botones.forEach(boton =>
       {
           boton.disabled = true;
       });
       
       e.target.disabled = false;
   });
});
```

Como ves, a cada evento adjunto aplico un segundo iterador que inhabilita todos los botones

```
botones.forEach(boton =>
{
    boton.disabled = true;
});
```

Para luego habilitar aquel que disparó el evento

```
e.target.disabled = false;
```

Donde `e` es un parámetro de objeto que representa el evento, `target` es una propiedad de este objeto que devuelve el elemento que disparó el evento y con esto, `disabled = false` a dicho elemento.

---

Adjunto un ejemplo funcional que puedes probar:

```js
var botones = document.querySelectorAll('.boton');

botones.forEach(boton =>
{
   boton.addEventListener('click', (e) =>
   {
       botones.forEach(boton =>
       {
           boton.disabled = true;
       });
       
       e.target.disabled = false;
   });
});
```

```html
<button class="boton">Boton 1</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 2</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 3</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 4</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 5</button>
<button class="boton">Boton 6</button>
```

Adelante, siéntete libre de agregar tantos botones como desees en el `HTML`. El código los detectará sin que tengas la necesidad de modificar el código `JavaScript`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, esperare la respuesta.

Comment: @Saza.P Gracias por entender. Mi solución te permitirá inhabilitar todos los botones que presenten la misma clase, activando solo aquel al que diste click. Es más práctico que buscar uno a uno por id.

Comment: es justo lo que busco, mil gracias de verdad!!

Comment: @Saza.P Listo, espero te sirva. Recuerda, quedo atento a cualquier duda o inconveniente que tengas. Además, si consideras de utilidad a mi respuesta, por favor, márcala como aceptada.

Comment: muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, claro que lo hare!!

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo tenías casi, solo tienes que cambiar el true por el false.
Dale a Ejecutar a ver si te sirve. Es esto lo que buscas o lo he entendido mal?

Un saludo

```js
function active(id) {
          document.getElementById('boton1').disabled=true;
          document.getElementById('boton2').disabled=true;
          document.getElementById('boton3').disabled=true;
          document.getElementById(id).disabled=false;
    }
```

```css
 .boton {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 95px;
        height: 70px;
        background: #51be44;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 300;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: .3s ease all;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
       
     }

 {

 }
 .boton::after:enabled{
     content:"";
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     background:#08700d;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:1;
     top:-90px;
     left: 0;
     transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
 }
 .boton:hover::after:enabled{
     top:0;
 }

 .boton:enabled span{
     position:relative;
     z-index:2;
     transition: .3s ease all;
 }

button:disabled,
button[disabled]{
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<button class="boton" id="boton1" onclick=" active(id)" value="0"><span class="text-white font-italic"> En carga </span>  <span class="text-white font-italic display-3">
            <asp:Label ID="lblencarga" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></button>
<button class="boton" id="boton2" onclick=" active(id)" value="0"><span class="text-white font-italic"> En uso </span>  <span class="text-white font-italic display-3">
            <asp:Label ID="Labelenuso" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></button>
<button class="boton" id="boton3" onclick=" active(id)" value="0"><span class="text-white font-italic"> Extraviado </span>  <span class="text-white font-italic display-3">
            <asp:Label ID="Labelperdido" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></span></button>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, si, es algo asi lo que estaba buscando, lo has entendido bien

Comment: Perfecto. Lo he editado pues para que tenga en cuenta los estilos que tienes definidos. Ejecuta y verás, echa un vistazo y em dices, un saludo!